# Disappearing hyphens in a ShapeFile date field

Tags: c#, gis

I am using the EGIS library for C# and am getting a date field from a ShapeFile, which is formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd`, though the issue is that some ShapeFiles work fine, whereas some are returning in the format `yyyyMMdd`. Only one line of code is used to import this field:

```
tempVals.Add(sf.GetAttributeFieldValues(i)[i2].Trim());
```

The attribute table of the ShapeFile definitely includes these dashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not the most succinct fix, I have just fixed this issue by reading the attribute field name first, then if it is a date formatting it myself:

```
tempVals.Add(title == "date" 
? string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",firstDatePart,secondDatePart,thirdDatePart)
: sf.GetAttributeFieldValues(i)[i2].Trim());
```